# Не корректное отображение анимации на айфоне

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Возник проблемный момент в использовании анимации. На десктопе все работает как надо, но когда загружаешь страницу на айфоне, то эффект срабатывает, а затем блок исчезает, пока не покрутишь экран. В чем причина и как справиться?

HTML

```
<img class="bounceIn" src="https://img.joinfo.ua/i/2017/04/150x117/58ef934331486.jpg">
```

CSS

```
.bounceIn {
        animation: bounceIn 2s ease-in;
-webkit-animation: bounceIn 2s ease-in;
}

@keyframes bounceIn {
from, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, to {
       animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
}

0% {
       opacity: 0;
       transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
}

20% {
       transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
}

40% {
       transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
}

60% {
       opacity: 1;
       transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
}

80% {
       transform: scale3d(.97, .97, .97);
}

to {
       opacity: 1;
       transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}
}
```

Comment: попробуйте добавить -webkit преффикс - https://jsfiddle.net/99vt8xta/

Comment: ох, точно! Вендорные преффиксы, забыла о них. Спасибо @soledar10 вам большое!